# How should I deal with multiple classes used in the same algorithm in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, helper, class

I have a situation where I am building a module for Magento2 with 3 Models that kind of interact with each other depending on the situation.

I tried to inject the classes withing them selves but that doesn't seem correct, so I ended up putting all my business logic into the Helper class. I know I shouldn't do that (right?), so what else can I do in a situation like that?

My module is an endpoint API that receives a request, process it and return a response, so everything is done under the hood, with one view, one block and one controller.

Thank you